# C++ equivalent to Java's `super.func();`?

Tags: java, c++, virtual-functions

I was pretty long in some Java project, and calling the parent's virtual functions went like this:

```
int func(..) {
    super.func(..);
}
```

But now as I return to C++, this is the way I thought It'd work (for Constructors this works) like this, but I was mistaken. I even forgot how this is called. `((Component)this)->func();` doesnt work either, so I'm lost.

```
int Label::func() : Component::func() {
}
```

How is it done correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The syntax you're trying to use is an initialization list (the `: ...` syntax after a function declaration). It only applies to constructors and is used to initialise the member variables of the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call function from super-class explicitly:

```
int Label::func() 
{
    return Component::func();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this before (although in C++ people often say Base instead of Super):

```
class Label : Component
{
   typedef Component Super;

   int func()
   {
     Super::func();
   }
};
```